# Display total sales per brand

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have 3 tables.

***BRANDS***

```
CREATE TABLE BRANDS (
    id_brand BIGINT(4) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (name)
)
```

***PRODUCTS***

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCTS (
    id_product BIGINT(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    code VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    price FLOAT(6,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    is_discounted TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
    discount_percentage INT(2) NOT NULL,
    discounted_price FLOAT(6,2) NOT NULL,
    description TEXT NOT NULL,
    stock INT(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    photo_1 VARCHAR(50),
    product_type_id BIGINT(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    brand_id BIGINT(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (product_type_id) REFERENCES product_types (id_product_type),
    FOREIGN KEY (brand_id) REFERENCES brands (id_brand),
    is_visible TINYINT(1) NOT NULL
)
```

***PRODUCT SALES***

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCT_SALES (
    id_product_sale BIGINT(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    QUANTITY INT(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    sale_date DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    total_price FLOAT(12,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,

    user_id BIGINT(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES USERS(id_user),

    product_id BIGINT(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES PRODUCTS(id_product),

    payment_method_id BIGINT(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (payment_method_id) REFERENCES PAYMENT_METHODS(id_payment_method),

    sale_status_id BIGINT(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (sale_status_id) REFERENCES SALE_STATUS(id_sale_status)

)
```

I need a query to display the ammount of produces sold per brand. 
I should get the following

- Intels - 27
- Western - 5
- GeForce - 10

But i get

- Intels - 42

This is how i tried to get the result i need.

```
SELECT b.name, sum(ps.quantity)
FROM Product_Sales ps 
JOIN Products p
ON ps.product_id = p.id_product
JOIN Brands b 
ON b.id_brand = p.brand_id
```

What's wrong with my query? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you running? On most servers, that query would have failed. Check your SQL_MODE and add sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY' to it - without it, your queries will return a random answer  - i.e. in this case, the server chose to show Intel, but there's nothing to stop it showing Western tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you're missing a `GROUP BY`! To answer your question, I did the following:

Created tables (relevant fields only):

```
CREATE TABLE brand
(
  brand_id INTEGER,
  name VARCHAR(25)
);

CREATE TABLE product 
(
  product_id INTEGER,
  brand_id INTEGER,
  name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE product_sale 
(
  product_sale_id INTEGER,
  product_id INTEGER,
  quantity INTEGER
);
```

Then I created some sample records:

```
INSERT INTO brand VALUES (1, 'Ferrari'), (2, 'Lamborghini'), (3, 'Porsche');

INSERT INTO product VALUES (1001, 1, 'TestaRossa'), (1002, 1, 'Dino'), (2001, 2, 'Countach'), (2002, 2, 'Diabolo'), (3001, 3, 'Cayenne'), (3002, 3, '911'), (3003, 3, 'Boxter');

INSERT INTO product_sale VALUES (500001, 2001, 45), (500002, 1001, 12), (500003, 3003, 7), (500004, 3001, 750), (500005, 3001, 400);
```

and then ran this query:

```
SELECT 
  b.name AS "Brand name", 
--  p.name as "Product name", 
  SUM(ps.quantity) AS "Quantity"
FROM brand b
JOIN product p
ON b.brand_id = p.brand_id
JOIN product_sale ps
ON p.product_id = ps.product_id
GROUP BY b.name;  -- p.name
```

I left in the extra p.name fields (commented out with --) so that you can see how the query was constructed. Take out the comments and have a look.

Result:

```
Brand name  Quantity
Ferrari     12
Lamborghini 45
Porsche     1157
```

All of this can be found at db-fiddle [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/88nZ5Gdq3rqCYJ6ipceuiA/1). For future reference, it's better to have a [Minimum Complete and Verifiable Example](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2990/minimal-complete-and-verifiable-example) (preferably complemented with a fiddle) which a) means that everyone is singing off the same hymnsheet - i.e. **your** data and b) there's no duplication of effort. You will obtain quicker and better answers with a well-constructed fiddle. You might also like to take a look [here](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql), and maybe take the tour and visit the helpdesk.

These sites are a great resource, all the more so if you take the time and effort to follow the guidelines. p.s. welcome to the forum!

Comment: Had a product_sale record with quantity and product_id inverted! :( - it's all good now!